# How to include graphics in mxGraph/JGraph format?

Tags: graphics

The [draw.io](http://draw.io) diagram editor exports to XML in mxGraph/JGraph format, which is human readable and convenient for tracking changes (the SVG export of draw.io has some bugs for now so the native XML is preferred).

How can I include graphics in mxGraph/JGraph format in a document?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: if you are generating pdf in the end then at some point you need a jgraph-pdf convertor, if you have such a tool then just convert and include the resulting pdfs. Oh I just tried it, it has an export to pdf built in, so you can use that.